# CSV data formatting in a linear way

Tags: c#, csv

I have a for loop which in which in every cycle i get 5 values.
I put the in CSV file but the data arrangement is not proper.

```
for (int i = 0, offset = 5; i < num_meters; i++, offset += 25)
{   

    float f_voltage, f_current, f_kw, f_kwh, f_freq, f_pf;
    f_voltage = (float)Math.Round(System.BitConverter.ToSingle(my_app_msg.msg_data, (offset + 1)), 2);    // voltage
    f_current = (float)Math.Round(System.BitConverter.ToSingle(my_app_msg.msg_data, (offset + 5)), 5);    // current
    f_freq = (float)Math.Round(System.BitConverter.ToSingle(my_app_msg.msg_data, (offset + 9)), 5);    // freq
    f_pf = (float)Math.Round(System.BitConverter.ToSingle(my_app_msg.msg_data, (offset + 13)), 5);   // pf
    f_kw = (float)Math.Round(System.BitConverter.ToSingle(my_app_msg.msg_data, (offset + 17)), 2);   // kw
    f_kwh = (float)Math.Round(System.BitConverter.ToSingle(my_app_msg.msg_data, (offset + 21)), 2);    // kwhr
    //Store in CSV
    vol2 = f_voltage.ToString();
    Curr2 = f_current.ToString();
    Feq2 = f_freq.ToString();
    PF2 = f_pf.ToString();
    power2 = f_kw.ToString();
    energy2 = f_kwh.ToString();
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    string Data = (time.ToString("u") + "," + power + "," + energy + "," + vol + "," + Curr + "," + Feq + "," + PF + "," + space + ",");


    //Putting in CSV
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathname + "MeterLogDataON_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(Data + "\t");
    }
}
```

But the value I want in CSV is like this.

```
VAlue1 VAlue1 VAlue1 VAlue1 VAlue1 | VAlue2 VAlue2 VAlue2 VAlue2 VAlue2 | VAlue3...so on.
```

but i facing problem as my data is stored in this way

```
VAlue1 VAlue1 VAlue1 VAlue1 VAlue1
VAlue2 VAlue2 VAlue2 VAlue2 VAlue2
```

Comment: Please show the code that actually writes the values to the CSV.

Comment: @Enigmativity i have posted it above

Comment: Use `Write()` instead of `WriteLine()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create a new line at each loop just use sw.Write instead of sw.WriteLine

```
 //Putting in CSV 
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathname + "MeterLogDataON_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv", true)) 
 { 
     sw.Write(Data + "\t");
 }
```

This will create an additional tab at the end of the loop, and your code opens and closes the stream at each loop. I suggest to change this code to use a StringBuilder where you can add the text while you loop over your data and write everything at the end

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for (int i = 0, offset = 5; i < num_meters; i++, offset += 25)
 {   
     ....................
     string Data = ......
     sb.Append(Data + "\t");
 }
 // Remove the last tab
 if(sb.Length > 0) sb.Length--; 

 string filename = (pathname + "MeterLogDataON_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv"
 File.WriteAllText(filename, sb.ToString());
```

or, if you have previous data to append to

```
 File.AppendAllText(filename, sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

***Try `Write(string value)` Method instead of `WriteLine(string value)` eg. `sw.Write(Data + "|");`***

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathname + "MeterLogDataON_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv", true))
{
            sw.Write(Data + "|");
}
```